# Literature on Lateral cauchy problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Can you please provide me with books that deal with lateral cauchy problem?

Also introductory articles are fine by me.

Is this topic covered in books like Evans', Taylor's, Hilbert-Courant's or other do specify where can I find a coverage of this topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Victor Isakov's [Inverse Problems for Partial Differential Equations](https://books.google.nl/books/about/Inverse_Problems_for_Partial_Differentia.html?id=fqcgg3iPhvoC&redir_esc=y) has a quite extensive treatment of the Cauchy problem with lateral boundary data, see chapters 3, 7, 8.